# Verify method call in constructor

Tags: groovy, spock

I've the following specification:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib:3.1') 
@Grab('org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.3') 

import spock.lang.*

class Whatever extends Specification {

    def "bind view to object in constructor" () {
        given:
        def view = Mock(View)
        def binder = Mock(Binder)

        when:
        def holder = new Holder(binder, view)

        then:
        1 * binder.bind(holder, view)
    }
}

class Binder {
    def bind(Holder holder, View view) {}
}
class View {}

class Holder {
    Holder(Binder binder, View view) {
        binder.bind(this, view)
    }
}
```

which fails with:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: holder for
>   class: Whatever

on the following line:

```
1 * binder.bind(holder, view)
```

in `then` block.

I know why it fails, since `then` is evaluated before `when` block. The question is, how can it test this `binder.bind()` constructor invocation without any tricky workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define `holder` in the `given:` block:

```
class Whatever extends Specification {
    def "bind view to object in constructor" () {
        given:
        def view = Mock(View)
        def binder = Mock(Binder)
        def holder

        when:
        holder = new Holder(binder, view)

        then:
        1 * binder.bind(holder, view)
    }
}
```

However, that fails:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * binder.bind(holder, view)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * binder.bind(Holder@519b27f6, Mock for type 'View' named 'view')
```

because when the *interaction* is verified `holder` is not assigned yet. So to test the interaction, it is better to do:

```
class Whatever extends Specification {
    def "bind view to object in constructor" () {
        given:
        def view = Mock(View)
        def binder = Mock(Binder)

        when:
        new Holder(binder, view)

        then:
        1 * binder.bind(!null, view) // or 1 * binder(_ as Holder, view)
    }
}
```

If we still want to check `holder` we need a [closure to capture the arguments](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/spocklight-writing-assertions-for.html):

```
def "bind view to object in constructor" () {
    given:
    def view = Mock(View)
    def binder = Mock(Binder)
    def holder
    def argHolder

    when:
    holder = new Holder(binder, view)

    then:
    1 * binder.bind(*_) >> { arguments ->            
        argHolder = arguments[0]
        assert view == arguments[1]
    }
    assert argHolder == holder
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this solution. This is also a workaround.

Comment: Just added an example showing how to capture arguments with a closure.